# JPA entity loading lazy collections while accessing some other method in entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i have a parent-child entities (Party & its accounts), code is mentioned below. Party has One-to-many relationship with accounts and its lazy loaded. My question is when i load PartyEntity and invoke its **test** method then why JPA (hibernate) is loading accounts which is lazy-loaded. i am not accessing accounts in test method:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARTY")
public class PartyEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARTY_ID")
    private String partyId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "party", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<PartyAccount> accounts = new HashSet<>();   

    public String getPartyId() {
        return partyId;
    }

    public void setAccounts(Set<PartyAccount> partyAccounts) {
        this.accounts = partyAccounts;
    }

    //**Call to this method executes query to fetch accounts**
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: does it change when you declare as `private Set<PartyAccount> accounts;` (i. e. remove `new HashSet<>()`)?

Comment: why not look at the log? Post the access code, and put a line in the log when you enter that method and a line in the log when you exit it ...

Comment: Are you sure that accounts are eager loading? Show the PartAccount code too.

Comment: @AlexSalauyou that is absolutely the wrong answer, collections MUST be initialized.

Comment: @Amalgovinus if used in transaction boundaries, unitialized collections are ok -- that is exact purpose of `PersistentSet`, `PersistentBag` implementations.